# Select all rows except one in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use a `SELECT` statement and fetch all rows from a table except for one which has an `id` of `4` - is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have a few options:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id != 4;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT id = 4;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id <> 4;
```

Also, considering perhaps sometime in the future you may want to add/remove id's to this list, perhaps another table listing id's which you don't want selectable would be a good idea.

In which case you would have:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM exempt_items_table);
```

Comment: am i doing the right thing here? `SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE NOT idAlbum = 4 '".$rowAlbums['idAlbum']."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Comment: If I understand correctly - "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE NOT idAlbum = " . $rowAlbums['idAlbum'] . " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"

Answer (score 8):

```
select * from table where some_id != 4
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from <table name> where <column - name> != <value>;
```