# mySQL how can I restrict a query by a particular id when using multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT u.id, name AS user_name, phone, site_name, site_description, monitor_id, user_id, computer_id, site_id, computer_name, computer_description
FROM users AS u
JOIN
(
SELECT s.id, name AS site_name, description AS site_description, computer_id, user_id, computer_id, site_id, computer_name, computer_description
FROM sites AS s
JOIN
(
SELECT monitor_id, user_id, computer_id, site_id, computer_name, computer_description
FROM service_log AS sl 
JOIN 
(
SELECT id, site_id, name AS computer_name, description AS computer_description
FROM computers) 
AS c ON sl.computer_id = m.id) 
AS tab1 ON tab1.site_id = s.id) 
AS tab2 ON u.id = tab2.user_id
```

This works fine, and outputs a list as expected like this:

```
id | user_name | phone | site_name | site_description | monitor_id | user_id | computer_id | site_id | computer_name | computer_description
 1 | john      | 12345 | home      | Johns house      |     1      | 234     | 123         | 22      | asd           | Tandy TRS-80
```

So now I want to restrict the results by the id's. 
I thought that I could do this by adding a `WHERE` clause in the second select from the bottom, to restrict by computer_id for example, like this:

```
(
SELECT monitor_id, user_id, computer_id, site_id, computer_name, computer_description
FROM service_log AS sl 
WHERE computer_id  IN ('123')   //ADDITIONAL CLAUSE HERE
JOIN 
(
SELECT id, site_id, name AS computer_name, description AS computer_description
FROM computers) 
AS c ON sl.computer_id = m.id) 
AS tab1 ON tab1.site_id = s.id) 
AS tab2 ON u.id = tab2.user_id
```

But this doesn't work. 
However, if I run that particular statement without the joins like this:

```
   SELECT monitor_id, user_id, computer_id, 
   FROM service_log AS sl 
   WHERE computer_id  IN ('123')
```

It works without any problems. I'm must be doing something wrong with how I perform the joins. 
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: don't add { WHERE computer_id  IN ('123') } in between JOIN clauses. add that line after all JOINs in subquery

Comment: You haven't included `c` in your `on` statements.  You should fix your `from` clause so you are joining two tables at a time.  It would be easier to follow the logic and you would immediately see that `c` has no `join` conditions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260449/select-all-rows-except-one-in-mysql    this question may help you.

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not work"? Do you get an exception, do you stop getting results - please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, I was getting an exception saying the format of the query was incorrect.  It's been solved now by @ASh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id, name AS user_name, phone, site_name, site_description, monitor_id, user_id, computer_id, site_id, computer_name, computer_description
FROM users AS u
JOIN
(
SELECT s.id, name AS site_name, description AS site_description, computer_id, user_id, computer_id, site_id, computer_name, computer_description
FROM sites AS s
JOIN
(
SELECT monitor_id, user_id, computer_id, site_id, computer_name, computer_description
FROM service_log AS sl 
JOIN 
(
   SELECT id, site_id, name AS computer_name, description AS computer_description
   FROM computers 
       #additional clause here
   WHERE id  IN ('123')
) 
AS c ON sl.computer_id = m.id) 
AS tab1 ON tab1.site_id = s.id) 
AS tab2 ON u.id = tab2.user_id
```